# Align text to the baseline of another element's first line of text

Tags: css, alignment, typography

Is it possible to align the text of one elements to the first line of text of another?

Both elements are variable length, so they might be more than one line.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible.
You should get familiar with flexbox. The css property you are looking for is

```
align-items: baseline
```

Here you will find a great overview on flexbox in general:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

I've build a quick example on codepen:
http://codepen.io/durchgemacht/pen/EjVXEW?editors=110

Comment: Thanks, this works, but that link is unfortunately dead.  (maybe just remove it if it's not worth re-creating)